# Find the ID of a nested element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="div1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="iwantthis"> </div>
</div>
```

- The ID of the parent DIV will be always the same meaning `#div1` won't change
- The ID of the children DIV `#iwantthis` is generated dynamically

I need to get the value of that dynamic ID and I can't use `.find()` method since it's tied to a given selector. I have search for this and a lot of topics comes out but none fit my scenario (or at least I couldn't find it).

What's the best way to find such ID value?

> Note: In addition to the post keep this in mind: at the moment I will have 4 DIV before the
>   current one holding the dynamic ID but this could change at any
>   moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `context` of `jQuery()` to `#div1`, select child element having attribute `[id]` or specific `id`

```
var div = $(" [id]", document.getElementById("div1"));
var id = div.attr("id");
```

Comment: @Dekel You are missing space before `[id]`. What do you mean by "makes much more sense"?

Comment: @Dekel your way is returning an Object instead of the ID

Comment: Why use `document.getElementById` if you have jQuery? :)

Comment: @Dekel Why use jQuery? `jQuery()` will call `.getElementById()` internally. Can save a function call to `jQuery()`

Comment: Correct, but if you already using jquery I think it makes much more sense not to combine code (even if it's only for readability). And regarding the space - You don't need the space there...

Comment: @ReynierPM, what do you mean?

Comment: You **do** need the `attr('id')`. All I said was to use `$("[id]", $("#div1"));` instead of `$(" [id]", document.getElementById("div1"));`. Drop the `document.getElementById` if you use jQuery... Thats all.

Comment: @Dekel Using `$("#div1")` returns same result, though not necessary to call `jQuery()` again. `document.getElememtById("div1").querySelector("[id]")` should return same result as well

Comment: I agree. All I said was that If you are using jQuery - use it to make your code readable :)

Comment: @Dekel _"And regarding the space - You don't need the space there"_ The space character is included at `selector` at `jQuery()` call `$("[id]", $("#div1"))`. The space character is needed for correct `css` selector to reference target element.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many `div`s before the item, then you can use following selector.

```js
var selector = "#div1>";

// loop 4 times, replace with how many div's before "wanted" div
// of course it can be a variable
for(var i = 0; i<4; i++) { 
    selector += "div+";
}

selector += "div";
console.log($(selector).attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="iwantthis"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the child selector relationship with attribute selector

```js
var $target = $('#div1 > div[id]'); //use the id attribute to select the target element
$target.addClass('selected');

//since the target is the last child you can use that relationship also

$('#div1 > div').last().html('Using last child');
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#div1 div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="iwantthis"></div>
</div>
```